# Solve an improper integral with help of Basset's integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, special-functions, fourier-transform

I am trying to calculate the integral of the form
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)(2r)^n}{\sqrt{\pi} \lambda^n r} \int_0^\infty dQ \frac{\lambda^{2n}\sin(Qr)}{(\lambda^2 + r^2)^{n+1}}Q
\end{align*}
$$

An idea was to use Basset's integral to solve it,
$$
\begin{align*}
K_n(\lambda r)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)(2r)^n}{\sqrt{\pi} \lambda^n} \int_0^\infty dQ \frac{\cos(Qr)}{(\lambda^2 + r^2)^{n+1}}
\end{align*}
$$
Differentiating under the integral sign is the way I believe. How to differential the modified Bessel's function of second kind $K_n(\lambda r)$ with respect to $r$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  Let $f(r)$ be given by the initegral

$$\begin{align}
f(r)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(Qr)}{Q(\lambda^2+Q^2)^{n+1}}\,dQ\\\\
\end{align}$$

Owing to the uniform convergence of the integral of the differentiated integrand, we can differentiate under the integral.  Proceeding and using [Basset's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#Px1) we find that

$$\begin{align}
f'(r)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(Qr)}{(\lambda^2+Q^2)^{n+1}}\,dQ\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^{1/2} r^{n+1/2}}{n!(2\lambda)^{n+1/2}}K_{n+1/2}(\lambda r)
\end{align}$$

Comment: So, to get $f(r)$, do i need integrate the last expression?

Comment: Yes.  Integrate the expression with respect to $r$.

Comment: Can you please help with it, i tried that too initially, but the integral seems to be non trivial.

Comment: Ah.  I'm not sure if this has a nice closes form.

Comment: @user35952 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I figured that my initial question was wrong, I have modified it now, you can answer accordingly.